# Root name based on class field for an xml serialized object with jackson

Tags: java, json, xml, spring, serialization

First of all, let me thank you in advance for all of your help!

Let me explain my current problem:

I'm trying to wrap some legacy web service calls with a rest/json/swagger layer. The fact is those old services use a tricky propietary xml format, which looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<service_RegistroEventoSrv>      
  <inputMap type="map">
      <mensajeMT type="map">
          <identificador type="String">
              <_value_>USUPRUEBA</_value_>
          </identificador>
          <modo type="String">
            <_value_>1</_value_>
         </modo>

      </mensajeMT>

    </inputMap>
</service_RegistroEventoSrv>
```

I've been able to serialize most of the objects and fields but I have a problem with the root tag. The main class used for the serialization is the following one, but I need that root tag takes its value from the "serviceId" property

```
public class CafRequestObject<I,O> {
    private String serviceId;
    private I inputMap;
    private O outputMap;
    private RequestMetaInfo requestMetaInfo;
    private ResponseMetaInfo responseMetaInfo;
 ... getters and setters
}
```

In order to achieve that tricky and custom serialization, I have added some serializares to the jackson XmlMapper for spring rest template.

### CafRequestObjectSerializer

```
 public class CafRequestObjectSerializer  extends CafXsdSerializer<CafRequestObject> {
 public void serialize(CafRequestObject value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException, JsonGenerationException {
         final ToXmlGenerator xgen = (ToXmlGenerator) jgen;


         xgen.writeStartObject();
         addRequestMetaInfo(value.getRequestMetaInfo(),xgen);        
         addObject(value.getInputMap(), xgen,INPUT_MAP);         
         xgen.writeEndObject();

}    

   }
```

Is there any way to get the root name from a field value? This is mandatory in my situation, because every call must have a different root value (so no JsonRootName or XmlRootName is posssible for me)

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: can't you create your own annotation in order to understand if the field is a root field? Something like `@MyRootField`

Comment: Thanks for your response, Angelo! But... How would I chain it with the serializer? Via reflection? I don't know how to modify my serializer, in order to alter the root tag... :\

Answer (score 0):

I've finally found a solution. Maybe it is not the best, but at least works for me :)

I have extended jackson's class XmlSerializerProvider and overrided methods

*serializeValue* .

There is a section where code does the following stuff:

```
QName rootName = _rootNameFromConfig();
        if (rootName == null) {
            rootName = _rootNameLookup.findRootName(cls, _config);
        }
```

I have modified it's original behaviour in order to alter the way it gets the root tag, based on the field of my root class:

```
 QName rootName = _rootNameFromConfig();
        if (rootName == null) {
            if (value instanceof CafRequestObject){
                rootName= getRootNameFromServiceId((CafRequestObject)value);
            }
            else{
                rootName = _rootNameLookup.findRootName(cls, _config);  
            }

        }


protected QName getRootNameFromServiceId(CafRequestObject object){
     return new QName( object.getServiceId()+_SERVICE);
}
```

Thanks for your help!